# Tangent circle(s) for two other circles?

Tags: math, geometry

There are two circles: **a** centered at point **A**, and circle **b** (center at **B**). What is the equation to calculate 2D position of all or none tangent circles possible. Main constraint is, that radius is the same for all the circles. As far as I know, there should be either no solution (figure 2), or 2 solutions (figure 1). How to find out *if there are solutions*, and also *position of centers* of those solutions (**C** and **D**).

[image]
*Figure 1*: 2 solutions should be possible here

---

[image]
*Figure 2*: No solutions!

**Update (solution):**

1) Calculate distance from A to B -> **|AB|**:

[image]

2) Checks whether a solution exist, it exist only if:

[image]

3) If it exist, calculate half-point between points **A** and **B**:

[image]

4) Create normalized perpendicular vector to line segment **AB**:

[image]

5) Calculate distance from this H point to C point -> **|HC|**:

[image]

6) Finally calculate point **C** along the (HC) starting at X at distance |HC|:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A solution exists iff `d(A,B) = sqrt(2)*2*r`
2. To find the center of the solution circles, that will let you draw the circonferences, you can intersect the circle with center `(x_m,y_m)`, that is the medium point of the segment `AB`, of radius  `sqrt(2)*r`, with the line perpendicular to AB and passing from `(x_m,y_m)`

This should give you all the needed information to check if a solution exixsts, and if it does, to draw it.

Comment: But what is the radius of said circle?

Comment: OK, I would have preferred the solution for the points directly, that was exactly my reason to come here, because I wanted to avoid switching from my project to suddenly solving one equation for hours. I guess, I have no choice.

Comment: As far as i can see, there isn't a "nice and clean" way to describe the center points of C and D ... the only solution is, indeed, solve either the system i suggest you or the one tomalla pointed out ( I think mine should be easier becasue you have one linear equation and a quadratic one, instead of 2 quadratic)

Comment: The distance equation for check whether the solutions exist is OK. I'm now trying to figure out (because this is not geometry math, but C# programming language) how to actually calculate the line circle intersections, how to calculate half-line, etc. so lay down in math for hours (for me), instead of actually programming, therefore I'm doing exactly what I was trying to prevent by coming here. :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this question should migrate to a more math related site.

Try to imagine where these two tangent circles go when the circles **a** and **b** get further and further apart. They get closer to the line **AB**. Once the **AB** segment equals **4r** these two tangent circles will overlap. From now on, once circles **a** and **b** get further apart, there's no tangent circles whatsoever.

If you want to calculate the position of these circles, just assume that the distance between the centers is always **2r**:

[image]

You should get two, one or none solutions for xC and yC, which will be the centers of your tangent circles. I hope I haven't messed something up.

### Solutions

Provided you do know there are solutions ( just check if `d(A,B) <= 4r` ), these are the coordinates of your two circles:

http://pastebin.com/LeW7Ws98

A little scary, eh? But it's working. There are the following variables:

`x_A, y_A` - the coordinates of the circle A,

`x_B, y_B` - the coordinates of the circle B,

`r` - the radius.

I've checked the solutions with the values from one of my comments below. I think that you can copy these solutions and inject them into your code straight away (provided there's a sqrt function) and get the results after declaring some variables.

These solutions are loosely derived from the Save's proposition but I couldn't comment below his answer - I've got less than 50 reputation points, duh ... ( thanks SO! You're the man! ). However I'm pretty sure they should be valid for my system anyways. Cheers

Comment: Heh, I've asked yesterday a question on math stack exchange, and although it was being answered by a brilliant mathematician, he was confused by 2D coordinate system. So today I've decided to put it here, and I'm being already told. OK, if there is some 2D math graphics version of StackOverflow, I'm all for it :) Thanks for the equations, I'm checking it out.

Comment: I've tried it, and it doesn't work out. This looks like a a^2 + b^2 = c^2, but there is not always a 90° angle between AC and BC. That might be the reason.

Comment: a,b and c are circles not numbers so it is not what you said, but try the system Tomalla gave you and you will have the answer

Comment: I did try it. With these values A [62, 144], B [125, 44], C [145, 122], and radius = 43 (the values from picture actually). The sides come as not equal, not by a long shot. The equations also don't have any solutions. Oh, by using a, b and c, I wasn't referring to circles, but to original Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Tomalla: It is possible, that I did something wrong here, can you solve the equations for me fo xC and yC? xC = ..., yC = ..., because I'm unable to, I did tried some online solving sites, and they confirmed, that indeed it has no solution. So I'm confused.

Comment: Wait, what C? C is *unknown*, it's a variable. So with A(62, 144), B(125, 44) and r=43 you get two solutions: approximately C(41,61) and C(146,127). Graph these solutions and you'll see they're correct.

Comment: OK, my fault, it was probably caused by the rough approximation. I've plotted it with Wolfram (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-62%29%5E2%2B%28y-144%29%5E2%3D172%5E2%2C%28x-125%29%5E2%2B%28y-44%29%5E2%3D172%5E2), the results are different, but it looks better. But I'm still unable figure out the xC = ... I need a calculation for values. I'm trying to calculate the solutions, but the reason my math is rusty, is the reason I came here.

Comment: OK then ... provided you do know there are solutions ( just check if `d(A,B) <= 4r` ), these are the coordinates of your two circles:

http://pastebin.com/LeW7Ws98

A little scary, eh? But it's working. There are the following variables:

`x_A, y_A` - the coordinates of the circle A, 
`x_B, y_B` - the coordinates of the circle B, 
`r` - the radius. 

I've checked the solutions with the values from my previous comment. I think that you can copy these solutions and inject them into your code straight away (provided there's a sqrt function) and get the results after declaring some variables.

Comment: I've been using Wolfram to calculate this (this whole time), and it returned similar (mad) equation. I thought I must have do something wrong, but it seems the equation is really too much. More for a t-shirt than for a fast algorithm. I'll up your answer, but I'll now try use Save's more geometric solution using circle/ray intersections. Because calculating half-point is quite fast. Thank you for your time. At least I've found out, that Wolfram is really good at solving these equations for me (I was still doing pen&paper, so I guess I'll move to 21st century too). :)

Comment: If you've looked at the updated answer I've written there that these solutions are yielded from his answer: I've calculated the middle point of the segment **AB**, created a line perpendicular to AB and going through the middle point and checked which points on that line are **2r** away from point A or B.

You're complaining about the equation, but I thought it's the only way to deal with it: you're writing a program, so the explicit solutions are the way to go. But if you want only to draw the circles and leave the math behind, you could just calculate the approximate positions, right?

Comment: Oh, I've missed that, yeah unfortunately I'm writing a program. But I've solved your equations to (edited out crazy equation). So it is a similar madness.

Comment: But what do you need your equations for? For drawing or for math-like simulation? All I'm saying is that if it's the former, you can certainly simplify the solutions since the almost-infinite precision isn't really needed.

Comment: I'm now trying to calculate half-point X (quite easy [Ax + (Bx-Ax)/2, Ay + (By-Ay)/2]. And then I'm trying to find distance to C along the perpendicular line from X. That distance from XC should IMO be: (|AB|/2)^2 + |XC|^2 = |AC|^2. In other words I know |AB|, and I know |AC| = 2r. So I'm using vector math. Then I need to find-out point C, on that is |XC| on a vector perpendicular to AB, and starting at X. That's what I'm now meddling with.

Comment: The distance x should now be: http://tinyurl.com/qeltfgf (two solutions -/+). Then I use vector AB to find perpendicular one XC = [y, -x], normalize it, and use it C = [X.x + XC.x*x, X.y + XC.y * x] that should give me point C. Or so goes theory.

Comment: That is a really nice idea. Let's say you have vector *AB* and you have calculated the point X. So ... normalize vector AB, so that its length is 1. Let's say it's `[p,q]`. Then just rotate it by 90 degrees (now it's `[-q,p]`) and multiply it by `|CX|`, which you have from the Pythagorean theorem. Now? Just add this vector to X and substitute it from X to receive the two centers you were looking for.

This solution crossed my mind earlier on but it's weird I was looking for an explicit formula only... Of course you're writing a program and you can just write an **algorithm**, duh!

Comment: Gosh, you always have to be these few minutes earlier, don't you? Ah well, at least you have a nice solution right there :) Cheers

Comment: I've given the answer to Save, because he pointed me to the final idea, but thanks again.