# Find the position of a circle tangent to two other circles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Say there are 3 circles, A, centered at point a, B centered at point b, and C, centered at point c.  Each has a known radius independent of the others, Ar, Br, and Cr.  The positions of a and b are known, but the position of c isn't.

The distance between a and b will always be between (Ar + Br) and (Ar + Br + (2 * Cr)).

I'm looking for a pseudo-code algorithm to find the position of c so that circles A and C are tangent, and circles B and C are tangent.  There ought to be two solutions unless a and b are at their maximum allowed distance, in which case there would only be one.

Thank you, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about geometry, not programming.

Comment: I am looking for a pseudo-code solution that I can integrate into my program.  I argue that this *is* about programming.

Comment: Figure out the maths first.  Once you have the equation, conversion to code ought to be trivial.

Comment: My question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558487/tangent-circles-for-two-other-circles), except that my circles can have different radii from each other.  Figuring out the maths are where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

"Inflate" the circles A and B by Rc at the same time as you shrink C to a single point. Then the center of C appears as the intersection of the two inflated circles.

Write the implicit equation of the two circles and subtract one from the other; the quadratic terms cancel out, leaving the equation of a straight line (the line through the two intersection points).

```
(X-Xa)² + (Y-Ya)² = (Ra+Rc)²
(X-Xb)² + (Y-Yb)² = (Rb+Rc)²
    => by subtraction
(Xa-Xb)(2X-Xa-Xb) + (Ya-Yb)(2Y-Ya-Yb) = (Ra-Rb)(Ra+Rb+2Rc)
```

To solve this, you can express `Y` as a function of `X` using the linear relation, then substitute `Y` in the equation of one of the circles and solve the second degree equation in `X`, yielding two solutions.