# How do you calculate the position of different radius circles when the arc should always intersect with each other on 2 specific points?

Tags: geometry

This is way above my level, in any matter, programming and math. I'm just trying to simplify setup in our CNC-machine.

To the problem ill attach a pic that show roughly what I mean.
[Circle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgf5d.png)

So, the 2 small circles have always a known distance and size. 27.5 dia and 200 cc.
The bigger circles have always a known radius but will differ.
The goal is to know how to position the bigger circles, so it always lines up together with the smaller ones, arc to arc. Which will make them overlap with different radiuses.

I have tried googling. But have not been able to find any clear simple formula for me to calculate this value. Just a bunch of "advance" equations which doesn't make any sense to me :)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595264/find-the-position-of-a-circle-tangent-to-two-other-circles) post that describes the same problem, i think. But not sure how to calculate it myself...

Would be really impressed if someone has a solution to this, thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Let small roll radius is `r`, distance is `d`, large circle radius is `R`

Circle centers form isosceles triangle with side lengths `d`, `R+r`, `R+r`.

Large circle center y-coordinate (over triangle base) is (using Pythagoras theorem)

```
y = sqrt((R+r)^2-d^2/4)
```

Example of calculation:

[image]

Delphi code used to generate this image:

```
var
  x1, y1, x2, y2, lx, ly: Integer;
  r, Rrr, d: Integer;
begin
  x1 := 200;  y1 := 500;  d := 200;  r := 30;  rrr := 150;
  x2 := x1 + d;
  y2 := y1;
  lx := x1 + d div 2;     //large circle center
  ly := y1 - Round(Sqrt((Rrr+r)*(Rrr+r)-d*d/4));
  canvas.Ellipse(x1 - r, y1 - r, x1 + r + 1, y1 + r + 1);
  canvas.Ellipse(x2 - r, y2 - r, x2 + r + 1, y2 + r + 1);
  canvas.Ellipse(lx - Rrr, ly - Rrr, lx + Rrr + 1, ly + Rrr + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Either I did something wrong or it didn't really do the job.
The oversecting is happening at the bottom of the bigger circles. I need the oversecting to connect with the small circles...

Comment: Look at example picture calculated with described formula.

Comment: Is my picture what you want?